# Can I identify a "function" in an x86 binary?

Tags: language-agnostic, x86, code-analysis

"Function" meaning a chunk (or a graph of chunks) of the binary that starts at a point (likely arriving from one of the CALL instructions), possibly sets up a stack frame, and has one or more endpoints in the form of RETs (and depending on the calling convention it may also unwind said stack frame).

My current idea is to treat the various conditional branching instructions as junctions in a graph and do a Breadth-first search on the code this way. Is this viable at all? If not, what's a better approach?

*My objective with this is just what it is: extract the functions. Purely for the sake of doing it. Maybe doing something fancy later if I have the time and notion.*

Comment: Can you use a 3rd party library for this?

Comment: Sure I can, if it exists. It's just a hobby thingy, no arbitrary restrictions on anything. I can use whatever I want. Though, if there's a complete solution for this, I'd appreciate if it was open-source because I'm interested in the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a **disassembler library** like [**BeaEngine**](http://www.beaengine.org/) to do the hard work for you and then search on resulting mnemonics for **call**.

Comment: I'd say you'd do better looking for all `RETN (x)`'s then back tracing a start point for each function, that way you can catch unreferenced functions and functions in tables etc. there are some pretty heavy heuristics behind something like this (just see ollydbg), not for the feint of heart, unless your not banking on catching non exported symbols.

Answer (score 2):

Without a symbol table I would say: almost impossible. At least without false positives/negatives.

What you need first is a disassembler. Just looking for a byte combination won't cut it, the combination might be part of some "random" data. Then, tracing the CALLs is likely the best solution as a function doesn't necessarily always start with the same opcode sequence. But even a disassembler might have a hard time and get confused by embedded data in the text segment.

Even if you were able to find the functions, you cannot get their names without debug symbols (in the compiled program there's no need for names any more, only addresses).

Also, you'd have a very hard time finding out what kind of parameters the function accepts. For example, a function might accept 2 argument but uses neither. In this case you would need a function call and look at how the stack is prepared in advance of calling the function.

Comment: I don't care about the names, nor the parameters, just the blobs that make up the functions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look for things like:

```
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
sub     esp, ???

...
...

add    esp, ???
pop    ebp
ret
```